# LaTeX-Referenz package in MiKTeX

Tags: packages, miktex

Since last year, I noticed that in MiKTeX there is a package called `LaTeX-Referenz` but when I try to install it, it issues an error (note the 0 Bytes file size). Is this local to my computer only or does anyone have the same issue? See images below:

[image]

[image]

Comment: May you need to follow up on http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2288/

Comment: This is definitely a bug with MiKTeX, since [`latex-referenz`](http://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/LaTeX-Referenz) is not empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

Text below is now historic. The bug was fixed in the beginning of February 2014, cf. linked bug entry.

*Alas the fix consisted in removing the empty installation file, not in making it a full proper installation.*

---

I observe the same behaviour, and it is a known bug: [Package "latex-referenz" is empty](http://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2288/).

As long Christian Schenk (the developer) does not fix this, the only solution consists in *not* installing the package. This means, if one in the Package Manager selects all new installable package, `latex-referenz` must be unselected first before triggering the installation of the other packages.

There was already a posting in German newsgroup `de.comp.text.tex` ([“Miktex Package Manager”](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/de.comp.text.tex/D_lXYy7JcDU/-NzeZt4O0_AJ)) and I also pointed Christian to this by e-mail confirming the bug.

Just a bit more information:
On your computer you will find a file `latex-referenz.tpm` (should be in `<path-to-MiKTeX>\tpm\packages`). If you look in this file you can read a link: http://www.miktex.org/packages/latex-referenz and there in the moment of writing I clearly read (not to speak from packaging date):

```
Number of files:    0
Size on disk:   0 bytes
```